# How to customize Cast Dialog in the Google Cast Framework for Android

Tags: android, casting, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am trying to customize the Google Cast SDK's Cast Dialog (shown when you tap the cast button and shows the list of available devices), but i haven't found a way to do it.

Currently, it just shows an AlertDialog with a list of the available devices to connect.

What i want to do instead, is open an Activity that will show the list of devices with my own UI implementation.

This is the dialog i am trying to modify:

[image]

I've found many customization aspects about this SDK, but nothing related to this dialog.

Comment: show us the code

Comment: @user1241241 There is no code to show, that is what i need currently but i don't know how to get started

Comment: Please refer to this documentation: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/advanced#customizing_cast_dialogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i figured out a way to achieve this,
First i created a class that overrides **MediaRouteActionProvider** (which is the main class that controls that button's functionality)

```
public class CustomMediaRouteActionProvider extends androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteActionProvider {

    public CustomMediaRouteActionProvider(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MediaRouteButton onCreateMediaRouteButton() {
        return new CastButton(getContext());
    }
}
```

Then you're gonna need to override the button's functionality with your own, in my case i open a new activity.

```
public class CastButton extends MediaRouteButton {


    public CastButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CastButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.mediaRouteButtonStyle);
    }

    public CastButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), RemoteDevicesActivity.class);
        getContext().startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to modify your xml that contains this button (i assume that you already implemented this part)

Change the field **app:actionProviderClass** with your custom class (in this case CustomMediaRouteActionProvider) and you're done.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:title="@string/connect_to"
        android:id="@+id/cast"
        app:actionProviderClass="CustomMediaRouteActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Comment: After doing this, the cast button is not showing, did you encounter this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you have more details of final result of this? I need to do something similar but I don't get it how did you achieve it

Comment: Not sure what you need, but in the activity created i get the list of remote devices, here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506631/how-can-i-get-list-of-all-cast-devices-using-cast-sdk